# Prevent "open" class on LI where no children UL is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've this HTML for build a menu:

Original HTML:

---

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="first has_children current"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/home">Inicio</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/content/rates">Tarifas</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/payment/buy">Recargas</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/access-number">Números de Acceso</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="last has_children has_current"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/#">Ayuda</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="first has_children"><a 1="" href="http://www.alomicuba.com/how-it-works">Cómo funciona</a></li>
            <li class="last has_children current"><a 1="" href="http://www.alomicuba.com/">Llamar usando VoIIP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then I have this transformed, trough below jQuery code, the same HTML for menu:

Transformed:

---

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/home">Inicio</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/content/rates" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Tarifas</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/access-number" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Números de Acceso</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/contact" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://www.alomicuba.com/#" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Ayuda</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown"><a 1="" href="http://www.alomicuba.com/how-it-works" data-close-others="true" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Cómo funciona</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a 1="" href="http://www.alomicuba.com/">Llamar usando VoIIP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using this jQuery code to set some values on this HTML:

```
$("ul.nav li").each(function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this),
    cls = '';
    if ($this.hasClass('current'))
    {
        cls = 'active';
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('has_children'))
    {
        cls = 'dropdown';
        $this.children('.dropdown')
            .attr('class', 'dropdown-menu')
            .end()
            .children('a')
            .attr({
                'data-close-others': 'true',
                'data-hover': 'dropdown',
                'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
                'class': 'dropdown-toggle'
            });
    }
    $this.attr('class', cls);
});
```

For some reason all the links, even, those who don't need it are getting the `open` class when I click on any of them. For example `Tarifas`, `Números de Acceso` (don't need the `open` class) while `Ayuda` should get the class because it has childrens. This is making the links disabled at some point since they not respond to click event and I can go to `href` for those links. How I can prevent this behavior? Any help or advice?

You can test it [here](http://www.alomicuba.com/) is the main menu at top just behind `AloMiCuba.com` text above slider.

**Edit: What I need**

Taking as input the original source (the first HTML in the post):

1. Check for current class on each LI on ul.nav navbar-nav navbar-right if it's found (should be one time) then change this to `active`
2. Check for `has_children` class and if the current LI has UL inside like li.last has_children has_current has then remove all the classes on that LI and add `dropdown`.

**Edit: based on WereWolf code**

This is the final code I was looking for:

```
$('ul.nav')
      .find('li.current')
      .removeClass('current')
      .addClass('active')
      .end()
      .find('li.last')
      .removeClass('last')
      .end()
      .find('li.has_children:has("ul")')
      .children('.dropdown')
      .attr('class', 'dropdown-menu')
      .end()
      .children('a')
      .attr({
          'data-close-others': 'true',
          'data-hover': 'dropdown',
          'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
          'class': 'dropdown-toggle'
      })
      .find('li.has_children')
      .removeClass('has_children');
```

Comment: I've looked at this code, and looked at the code on your site. Your site is very difficult to view because it's in a minimized format. If you could pull out the relevant HTML and add it to your question it would be a great help - maybe even make a fiddle. PS - Your code above is very nicely organized - compliments!

Comment: @TimSPQR Done, I've edited the question and add more info, could you take a look again?

Comment: Ok, your $this is looking at all of the li under the original ul, and if any li has a class of 'has_children' then some other stuff is done, but I don't see any classes = has_children. I see an li that has .children(). Which do you mean? I'll keep looking at the code for anything else.

Comment: Comment out all of your js and add one line like this - alert( $('ul.nav').children('.active').length); then change the jQuery selector to 'ul', 'ul li' etc, and you can see how many of the children are selected. This may be your problem - I'll keep looking.

Comment: @TimSPQR I added the original source before transformation happen, take a look. The `open` class only is allowed on that LI with UL inside like the last one with `Ayuda` label

Comment: You are making it complex, just tell what do you want to be your `HTML` look like from original depending on what conditions.

Comment: Now I see, you didn't have the "add_children" class in your original post. I agree with Werewolf, it seems a bit complex. Can you just tell us what you want to do with the layout, then perhaps we might help you simplify it.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I added what I need to do in here, please take a look and edit the post, if you can, just leaving the relevant info

Comment: Did you check the answer @ReynierPM ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha based on your code I add some extra code since I'll like to remove `has_children` from the rest of LI but my code is failing since it doesn't remove the class otherwise the code works perfectly as I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Requirements:**
>
> 1. Check for current class on each LI on ul.nav navbar-nav navbar-right if it's found (should be one time) then change this to
>      active.
> 2. Check for has_children class and if the current LI has UL inside like li.last has_children has_current has then remove all the classes
>      on that LI and add dropdown.

If I understood then you may want this:

```
$('ul.nav')
.find('li.current')
.removeClass('current')
.addClass('active')
.end()
.find('li.has_children:has("ul")')
.attr('class', 'dropdown');
```

Right now you have two `li` items with class `current` so both is changing to `active` but if you want change only the first `li.current` (Direct decedent of `ul.nav`) to `li.active` then just change `.find('li.current')` to `.find(' > li.current')`. [An Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fvuy6/1/).

**Update:** According to following comment:

> based on your code I add some extra code since I'll like to remove
>   has_children from the rest of LI but my code is failing since it
>   doesn't remove the class otherwise the code works perfectly as I want

```
$('ul.nav')
.find('li.current')
.removeClass('current')
.addClass('active')
.end()
.find('li.has_children:has("ul")')
.attr('class', 'dropdown')
// Added new lines
.end()
.find('li.has_children')
.removeClass('has_children');
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvuy6/6/).